# How to set an id to elements created on the fly in KnockOutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

How to set an id to elements created on the fly in KnockOutJS. As you see I have two spans, one for the button, second one for the small icon on the corner of button(see image below). And all this for total of 6 elements. Now I dont know how to manage with css, cuz they have no unique ID.

 What to do?

```js
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

<script id="normal" type="text/html">
    <div class="ItemIndicateur">
        <span class="BuIndicateur" data-bind="text: $parent.CatFullName() == true ? CatNom : CatNomOnglet, click: $parent.ClickedItem, attr: { id : IdCat}" style="display:block; color: white; padding:10px" />
        <span class="NbDemandeDiv" data-bind="text: NbDemandeIndicateur,visible: IsNbDemandeIndicateur, attr: { id : $parent.IdNbDemande()}"></span>
    </div>
</script>
```

```html
<div class="ListeIndicateur" data-bind="template: {name: GetItemTemplate, foreach: ListeIndicateur},">
```

[image]

Comment: You're already using the solution?  `attr: { id : $parent.IdNbDemande()}`

Comment: Is this supposed to be in a `foreach` loop? If so you can use `$index` to make a unique id. Something like `attr: { id: 'someBaseId' + $index }`. Or if you are using your `IdNbDemande` function, pass `$index` to it and have it use it as part of the id.

Comment: `Now I dont know how to manage with css, cuz they have no unique ID.` have you considered using the `nth-child` selector?

Comment: this what I have in my `IdNbDemande()`

Comment: `public IdNbDemande() {
            var self = this;
            return ko.computed(function () {
                return "IdNbDemande" + self.IdCounter;
            });
            self.IdCounter++;
        }`

Comment: it works, IdNbDemande1, IdNbDemande2 .... but later on, if there'are changes in ko, it goes back again, and ID changes. How to fire that just once for each elements?

Answer (score 1):

Use the css binding provided by knockout.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

1. Create a class in your CSS to that has the styles you want. You may need more than one depending on your needs
2. When an element meets a criteria apply the css class via the binding

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
<script id="normal" type="text/html">
    <div class="ItemIndicateur">
        <span class="BuIndicateur" data-bind="text: $parent.CatFullName() == true ? CatNom : CatNomOnglet, click: $parent.ClickedItem, attr: { id : IdCat}" style="display:block; color: white; padding:10px" />
        <span class="NbDemandeDiv" data-bind="text: NbDemandeIndicateur,visible: IsNbDemandeIndicateur, attr: { id : $parent.IdNbDemande()}, css: {'color1': NbDemandeIndicateur < 3, 'color2': NbDemandeIndicateur < 10}"></span>
    </div>
</script>
```